# Как получить все методы которые определены в классе, на Android 4.x?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как получить все методы которые определены в самом классе как публичные так и приватные в Android 4.X.

Comment: В смысле, вам нужен список всех методов какого то класса, чтобы узнать, какие методы у него есть и их сигнатуры, к примеру или что ?

Comment: @pavlofff до мне нужно получить все методы определенного класса, допустим "android.app.NotificationManager" но нужно получить также тип которые он может принимать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте про Java Reflectiion. Простой пример извлекающий все методы класса:

```
Class clz=myObject.class; //получаем ссылку на класс
Method[] methods = clz.getMethods();

for(Method method : methods){
    Log.i("CLZ", "method = " + method.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такая строчка вернёт вам массив *Method[]*, в котором будут все приватные и публичные методы

```
Method[] methods = ClassName.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Вывести можно так же просто:

```
for (Method method : methods)
    System.out.println(method);
```

Также есть метод `getMethods()`. Он вернёт все публичные методы этого класса, доступные в нём (т.е. он возвращает ещё и унаследованные методы, в то время, как `getDeclaredMethods()` возвращает методы, определённые (или переопределённые) только в этом классе, исключая просто унаследованные (`toString()` - исключение, он всё равно будет включён))

Вот вам полноценный пример, ловите:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method method : List.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            String returnType = method.getReturnType().toString();
            String methodName = method.getName();
            StringBuilder parameterTypes = new StringBuilder();
            for (Class<?> parameterClass : method.getParameterTypes()) {
                if (parameterTypes.length() != 0) parameterTypes.append(",");
                parameterTypes.append(parameterClass.getName());
            }

            System.out.printf("%s %s(%s)\n", returnType, methodName, parameterTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

Все манипуляции с методами делаются подобным образом

Comment: @pavlofff извиняюсь, а на андроиде ниже 4.x разве версия java ниже 1.1? к чему вопрос такой? если вы про enhanced-loop, то его не так уж и трудно заменить на обычный for

Comment: @PloadyFree а можно вывести еще тип которые принимает метод ? Потому что возвращает только сами названия, а нужно что то типа такого http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1440415648/226e8d81/9682963.png

Comment: @4BAL0V обновил ответ. вы это хотели?

Comment: Все же, думаю, если информация нужна для справки, то получать ее методом вывода на устройство - не лучший вариант, это неудобно. Так же остается вопрос, как убедится, что они принадлежат именно API14-19, если на устройстве другое API?

Comment: @pavlofff Это ознакомительный материал, который лишь показывает малую часть Reflection API. А от андроида это никак не зависит, ибо подобные методы появились в jdk 1.1. Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: в вопросе нужно получить методы для классов из API14-19, данный код вернет методы для API, который установлен на устройстве. Это может быть API9 или API20, к примеру. Или автору нужно , чтобы это выполнялось на устройстве с Android 4.x - не очень понятно, хотя ближе первое, потому что в разных API могут быть изменения

Comment: Да, недокументированные методы - они разные не только в разных версиях API, но и могут отличаться на устройства разных производителей

Comment: @pavlofff можно смотреть какой API на устройстве Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, и если она больше 19 и меньше 14 то делать нужное действие.

Прикол то весь в том что почти у каждого вендора методы могут быть свои и документации не найти на них

Answer (score 1):

На сайте http://developer.android.com собрана исчерпывающая информация по все методам всех классов всех версий Android API с подробным описанием и сигнатурами, правда только по публичным.
Например, [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) - версию API можно выбрать в верху левой панели со списком классов (API level:-) - Android 4.x это API 14-19.

Что касается приватных методов, полей класса и проч., тут можно обратиться на [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/), где представлены исходники многих фреймворков, ЯП и прочего, в том числе и Android. Слева там есть панель со всеми методами и полями в классе, а из списка можно выбрать версию API.
Например, [`NotificationManager`](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=NotificationManager) - выбрав Android 4.0.3, получаем такой [расклад в окне слева](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/NotificationManager.java#NotificationManager)(вкладка *Outline*) - зеленые кружки - публичные методы, красные квадраты - приватные, правда в данном классе таких методов нет, треугольники - поля класса и тд, там все подписано при наведении курсора. Тут же сигнатуры, типы входящих аргументов и возвращаемые значения.

На вкладке *Files* сверху той же панели слева можно выбрать другой класс этого же API. Очень удобно.

Comment: забавно, только всё это умеет делать IDE =) [пример](https://pp.vk.me/c623327/v623327902/40814/yGtkMOOUSsY.jpg)

Comment: Да, естественно .. в IDE не всегда удобно заниматься такими вещами. Мне проще на втором мониторе по grepcode найти, чем в IDE отвлекаться на API из проекта. К тому же, в IDE может не быть исходников API14-19, если он не установлен ранее в SDK и получить именно класс из API14 не так же просто, а вообще - да, умеет IDE это делать тоже.

Comment: Ну да, андроид-разработка несколько специфична в этом плане. Я привык, что API для Java 8 везде одинаковое) А вообще работать с андроидом на двух мониторах куда удобнее, раз уж API разное. Да в любом случае на двух мониторах удобнее)

Comment: У меня их три :) классическая схема: IDE - Интернет и прочие доки - Эмуляторы.